# Must a non-simple group have a normal Sylow subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory, simple-groups

In class, one way we're taught to prove a group is not simple is to exhibit a normal Sylow subgroup.

I'm wondering if the converse is true, i.e. if a group is not simple, must it have a normal Sylow subgroup? I can't seem to prove this is the case but I haven't been able to come up with a counterexample yet either.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For a counterexample, consider $S_n$, $n\geq 5$. No $p$-subgroup is normal as the only proper nontrivial normal subgroup is the alternating group.

Comment: In fact no Sylow subgroup of $S_4$ is normal. I think that's the smallest group with that property.

Comment: @DerekHolt I wasn't sure about that and was too lazy to try to check so I took the easy way out. Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 3):

Counterexample: if $S$ is a non-abelian simple group, then certainly $S \times S$ is not simple and has no normal Sylow subgroups.